# Differences between LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES and LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES?

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, makefile, system

What are the differences between `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` and `LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES` in Android build system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In native world(c or c++):
LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES means all the modules declared after this marco must be compiled and installed.
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES means that these modules will be linked and no need to use "dlopen" to use these libraries(but you should include the *.h files in your own module).